# When parsing a html file, how to get the table with some specific child in R?

Tags: html, r

I get a html with nested table:

```
html='<html>
<body><table><tr class="notChooseMe">
<td><table><tr class="chooseMe"></td>
<td><table><tr class="notChooseMe"></tr></table></td>
</tr></table>
</body></html>'
```

How can I extract the table with a "tr", which has the "chooseMe" class within the table? Please do not use the index to return the table since the position could change at anytime, for example,

```
html='<html>
<body>
<table><tr class="notChooseMe0"></tr><tr>
<td><table><tr class="notChooseMe1"></tr></table></td>
...
<td><table><tr class="notChooseMe2"></tr></table></td>
...
<td><table><tr class="chooseMe"></td>
...
<td><table><tr class="notChooseMeX"></tr></table></td>
</tr></table>
</body></html>'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the matching `tr` and then go back up to the parent:

```
library(rvest)

tab = read_html(html) %>%
    html_node("table tr.chooseMe") %>%
    xml_parent()
```

Output:

```
{xml_node}
<table>
[1] <tr class="chooseMe"><td>\n<table><tr class="notChooseMe"></tr></table>\n</td></tr>
```